# Dependency Injection with Adapter Pattern and Type Hinting

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to get my head around type hinting in combination with adapters.

The system fetches XML feeds via different services and updates the database with the changes - I am refactoring to help learn design patterns.

**Log Interface:**

```php
interface LoggerAdapterInterface {
    public function debug($string);
    public function info($string);
    public function error($string);
}
```

**MonoLog Adapter**

```php
class MonoLogAdapter implements LoggerAdapterInterface
{
    public $logger;

    public function __construct(\Monolog\Logger $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function debug($string)
    {
        $this->logger->debug($string);
    }

    public function info($string)
    {
        $this->logger->info($string);
    }

    public function error($string)
    {
        $this->logger->error($string);
    }
}
```

**FeedFactory**

```php
class FeedFactory
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function build(LoggerAdapter $logger, $feedType)
    {
        // eg, $feedType = 'Xml2u'
        $className = 'Feed' . ucfirst($feedType);

        // eg, returns FeedXml2u
        return new $className($logger);
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```php
// get mono logger
$monoLogger = $this->getLogger();

// create adapter and inject monologger
$loggerAdapter = new MonoLogAdapter($monoLogger);

// build feed object
$Feed = FeedFactory::build($loggerAdapter, 'Xml2u');
```

**Error**

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to FeedFactory::build() 
must be an instance of LoggerAdapter, instance of MonoLogAdapter 
given, called in /src/shell/feedShell.php on line 64 and defined in 
/src/Feeds/FeedFactory.php on line 25
```

So I am using the LoggerAdapter so that I am not tied to one logging platform. The problem is that when I create a new instance of MonoLogger and try to inject it into the factory - PHP type-hinting does not realize that MonoLogger implements LoggerAdapter.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Not familiar with PHP syntax, but in this line here: `public static function build(LoggerAdapter $logger, $feedType)`, should it not be `LoggerAdapterInterface`?  In terms of OOP, it seems to be breaking [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) to be depending on the classes (which I assume `LoggerAdapter` is) vs. the interfaces you've defined.  Also, as the error eludes to, your `MonoLogAdapter` is not a `LoggerAdapter` (but it is a `LoggerAdapterInterface`).

Comment: D'oh! Yes - thanks. Changing the type hint to LoggerAdapterInterface fixed it. Aahh - so will always try to depend on interfaces rather than classes.

Comment: Yes, according to OOP's Dependency Injection Principle - your application should rather consist of a lot of small interfaces than a lot of hard-coded classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ironcache suggested - use interface as argument in your `build` method.

```
public static function build(LoggerAdapterInterface $logger, $feedType)
{
    // eg, $feedType = 'Xml2u'
    $className = 'Feed' . ucfirst($feedType);

    // eg, returns FeedXml2u
    return new $className($logger);
}
```

*note: also check namespace*